# Why won't SQL return a value if I use "=" but will return if I use "like"?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here are my queries: 
(Won't return a value)

```
select * from T_VoucherHeaderEntry
where Vhe_VoucherNo = 'APV-1808-00160'
```

(Will return a value)

```
Select * from T_VoucherHeaderEntry where Vhe_VoucherNo like 'APV-1808-00160%'
```

I tried trimming my first query but it doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: share your table data otherwise how can we get why not return data

Comment: `=` wants exact 'APV-1808-00160' match. like with a trailing % wants begins with 'APV-1808-00160' but may have more characters at the end.

Comment: @MJH sorry, I copied the wrong query.

Comment: If you run `SELECT ASCII(RIGHT(Vhe_VoucherNo, 1)) FROM T_VoucherHeaderEntry WHERE Vhe_VoucherNo like 'APV-1808-00160%'` what does it return?

Comment: Can you trying running `select CONVERT(varbinary(max),Vhe_VoucherNo)` instead of `select *` for your `LIKE` query and copy and paste the *whole* result into your question (as text, not an image please)? (This will not fix the problem but should help us spot what the problem is)

Comment: @Diado It returns 32

Comment: @Mackoy That's your problem then - you have a space at the end of your data. The ascii code for '0' is 48. 32 is a space.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever here's the result
0x4150562D313830382D30303136300D0A20202020

Comment: @Diado - we cannot *just* be chasing a trailing space since `select CASE WHEN 'abc' = 'abc ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` returns 1 in all collations I can think if. Trailing spaces are effectively ignored for equality checks (see my comment on one of the question below for more details)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Hmm, true, I had forgotten about the space padding thing

Comment: Okay, so you actually have stored `<CR>`, `<LF>` and four additional spaces after your value. `TRIM` doesn't affect carriage return or linefeed.

Comment: Thank you so much @Damien_The_Unbeliever and Diado I stored <CR> with it which makes TRIM not effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have other control characters in your stored data, specifically carriage-return and line-feed. This highlights the issue and the final query finds all rows currently affected by this<sup>1</sup>:

```
;declare @t table (Val1 varchar(20))
insert into @t(Val1) values ('abc
    '),('def')

select * from @t where Val1 = 'abc'
select * from @t where Val1 like 'abc%'

select * from @t where Val1 like '%
%'
```

So, fix those rows however you choose to do so. Next, add a `CHECK` constraint on this column:

```
ALTER TABLE T_VoucherHeaderEntry
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_T_VoucherHeaderEntry_NoExoticChars
CHECK (Vhe_VoucherNo not like '%[^-A-Za-z0-9]%')
```

(It's expressed as a double negative to say we want to *disallow* any character in the provided range. We have to put `-` as the first character so that it's interpreted literally and not as a range separator)

And finally update your applications to not attempt to insert such bogus data in the first place.

---

<sup>1</sup>The third query identifies those specifically affected by `CR`/`LF` issue. For a more general approach, once you've decided on the appropriate character range to specify in your check constraint, a variant of that same approach will find rows that won't satisfy the check constraint for you to fix.

Answer (score 0):

if your `Vde_VoucherNo` column contain this `'APV-1808-00160'` value then definitely below should work and return data

```
select * from T_VoucherHeaderEntry
where Vhe_VoucherNo = 'APV-1808-00160'
```

in case of white-space  in your column value, you can use trim function

```
select * from T_VoucherHeaderEntry
where trim(Vhe_VoucherNo) = 'APV-1808-00160'
```

But if your column contain pattern of this values `APV-1808-00160` then like will work which is your 2nd query

```
Select * from T_VoucherHeaderEntry
where Vhe_VoucherNo like 'APV-1808-00160%'
```

BTW noticed the two query is from two different table , so that may be also reason

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to say about spaces. Space rules are odd in SQL and (effectively) trailing spaces are ignored when matching strings. (What the rules actually say is that for strings of unequal length, the shorter string is padded with spaces before comparison occurs. The effect is the same as ignoring training spaces)